# How to change Bar Chart Label to invisible if below certain value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stacked Bar Chart in SSRS.

If a bar is below certain value how to change label of this bar to invisible?

- For example if bar below 2,400,000 feet then label to invisible

[image: For example if bar below 2,400,00 then label to invisible]

Is this possible?

The bar labels have a visible property. But how to tell SSRS to decide on every x bar?

Comment: First create a parameter for the value. Then in the expression you want to use an immediate if "IIF". Ex: =IIF(SUM(Fields!YourMeasureName.Value) < Parameter!YourParameterName.Value, "", Format(SUM(Fields!YourMeasureName.Value), "0,000")). Sorry, I'm not sure if the syntax is right, I'm on my phone.

Comment: Why a new Parameter? I do not think this is the right way.

Comment: You want to use a parameter so that you are not hard coding your business rules in the expression.

Comment: You can set the parameter to not be visible as well as giving it a name that tells other developers what the value is for (self documentation).

Comment: Parameter Name = MinimumSquareFeet,
Parameter Value = 2,400,000

Comment: Why using parameter, why not just type in the number 2,400,400 as minimum?

Comment: You can, but it would be a bit easier to manage as a parameter or even a report variable.